# Visual Studio - Printing Element Of Array using Timer Control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am creating a program that prints the element of array one at a time (from top left to bottom right) using the timer control, however, it's not printing the elements one at a time, it prints all of them at the same time. I need help, below is a sample screenshot and my code so far.

[image]

```
Public Class SymbolDrawFRM
Private symbol(10, 10) As String

Sub Drawing()
    Dim s As String = ""
    For i = 1 To rowNUD.Value
        For j = 1 To columnNUD.Value
            s = s & symbol(i, j) & # & " "
        Next
        s = s & vbCrLf
    Next
    outputTBX.Text = s
End Sub

Private Sub startStopBTN_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startStopBTN.Click
    Timer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    Drawing()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the Array, and only using the NumericUpDown controls:

```
Private Sub startStop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles startStop.Click
    Timer1.Interval = 500
    Timer1.Enabled = Not Timer1.Enabled
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Static x As Integer
    Static y As Integer
    If x = 0 And y = 0 Then
        outputTBX.Clear()
    End If

    outputTBX.AppendText("# ")
    x = x + 1
    If x = columnNUD.Value Then
        x = 0
        outputTBX.AppendText(vbCrLf)
        y = y + 1
        If y = rowNUD.Value Then
            x = 0
            y = 0
            Timer1.Stop()
            MessageBox.Show("Done!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Idle_Mind, where do I put the rowNUD and columnNUD?

Comment: I didn't include them.  Are you wanting to make a grid based on those NumericUpDowns...or based on the Array itself?  Your original code is not using the array correctly.

Comment: The number of rows and columns are based on the NumericUpDowns

Comment: Okay.  Are we to completely ignore the array? `Private symbol(10, 10) As String`  How does that come into the picture?

Comment: I guess we can ignore the array as long as the rows and columns is base on the NUD controls